# How we can Create Simple CRUD application with Nodejs Express Firebase

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, express

I am a beginner and have some basic knowledge of Nodejs Express and MongoDB development. now I am thinking of changing my database from MongoDB to Firebase. can someone suggest me some basic tutorials for Nodejs/ Express and Firebase Simple CRUD Application? I have googled but didn't found any.

Comment: Alright so for first you should to learn how Node.JS works, and then you could start working with Express and Firebase. So it's very easy, you can type on google Node.JS and Express free course. and it gives you 100 of a results )

Comment: i know basics of nodejs and express and i have also created an application with MongoDB Express and Nodejs. but now i want to change the database from Mongodb to firebase

Comment: Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This is not an appropriate question for SO.

Comment: hey ! same prob here! did u find any tutorials ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this at once:

[Firebase CRUD Nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-crud)